# How to post multiple pictures with an open graph request to facebook?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uiimage, facebook-opengraph

Code that posts one image:

```
-(IBAction)postImageToFacebook:(id)sender {

    DLog(@"");


    NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [params setObject:self.textField.text forKey:@"message"];

    DLog(@"%@",[params objectForKey:@"message"]);

    if(self.imageView.image){
        DLog(@"not null");
        UIImage *_img = self.imageView.image;

        [params setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(_img) forKey:@"picture"];
    }



    [self performPublishAction:^{


        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                                     parameters:params
                                     HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                              completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                  id result,
                                                  NSError *error)
         {
             if (error)
             {
                 //showing an alert for failure

                 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                 message:@"unable to post"
                                                                delegate:nil
                                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];
                 [alert show];

             }
             else
             {
                 //showing an alert for success
                 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Posted!"
                                                                 message:@""
                                                                delegate:nil
                                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];
                 [alert show];
             }


         }];

    }];



}
```

Can I add another object for a duplicate key into the NSMutableDictionary?